# Definition of Normal Convergence. Which one is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, definition

Let us start with a given function $f_n$ defined on a certain domain $I$ and s.t. $f_n:I\mapsto\text{ some normed vector space}$. Let us consider:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\| := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_I |f_n(x)| < \infty\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\text{ is normally convergent}\tag{1}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\| := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_I |f_n(x)| < \infty\iff \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\text{ is normally convergent}\tag{2}$$

---

Which one is the correct definition of normal convergence? $(1)$ or $(2)$? Any reference?

Comment: (1) is not a definition because a definition is an "if and only if" statement between string of symbols, that is, is a logic equivalence between strings of symbols

Comment: This was exactly my thought. However, anywhere I find normal convergence definition as $(1)$. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence#Definition Why? @Masacroso

Comment: This is just the way definitions are usually written. When one writes "an integer is defined as *even* if it is divisible by $2$," it is also implied that "if an integer is not divisible by $2$, then it is not even."

Comment: @Strictly_increasing I see, in your example it seems that the "if" doesn't refer to a logic implication, it must be understood as an "exclusive if", that is, as an "if and only if" implicit statement. I dont know why someone downvoted your question but, considering the linked example, your question makes a lot of sense. +1

Comment: @Masacroso great, so it is true, *as well*, that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)\text{ is normally convergent}\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|f_n\| := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_I |f_n(x)| < \infty$$

Comment: @Strictly_increasing, yes, and if you put the arrow in the other direction it would be also true. That is: definitions are logic equivalence between string of symbols